# Email regular expression validator for allowing whitespace at start and end

Tags: asp.net, regex

Following expression work well for email validation with asp.net but does not allow whitespace at start and end.

```
 ^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$
```

Have any way to allow whitespace?

Here is full asp.net markup, I can not trim before validation.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="textbg text"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="EmailValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is not vaild."
            ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*$"
            ValidationGroup="register">Email is not vaild.</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you *want* to allow whitespace?

Comment: Why not trim before applying regular expression?

Comment: *Well* is an extremely relative term. I haven't seen many regexes that were less able to validate an e-mail address. Especially the `([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25}` part had me giggling. Also cool how `a@b.cde@f.gh` is considered a valid address.

Comment: [meme]Trim all the spaces![/meme]

Comment: I have edited the question. I m using RegularExpressionValidator control, i have no way to trim before validate

Comment: Hi GalacticCowboy, this is my client requirement. Moreover one may type " test@domain.com " instead of "test@domain.com" so is not it better to handle this by ignoring whitespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would echo the previous points suggesting trimming the input prior to validation. Trimming or ignoring whitespace is a pretty common requirement, so I would be very surprised if your validator couldn't handle it.

I would also point out an email address with that spaces on either end is an invalid email address, so passing it as valid is technically incorrect.

However, if it can't trim it, and you must pass it, then it is trivially easy to modify any regex to allow whitespace at either end.

White space is represented in regex with `\s`. Zero or more white spaces would be `\s*`.

Therefore, all you need to do is add `\s* to the start and end of the expression, immediately inside the`^`and`$` start and end markers, like so:

```
/^\s*(.......)\s*$/
```

(where `......` represents an expression to validate an email address (but probably not the one you've quoted in the question).

Hope that helps.

Comment: \w matches a word character.  \s is for whitespace.

Comment: @ElroyFlynn - heh. thanks for spotting the obvious mistake. Fixed it. I really shouldn't be answering questions when I'm tired.  ;-)

Comment: @Spudley Awesome! thank you very much. You did exactly that i want.

Answer (score 1):

Email validation using regular expressions are not easy. Since you're using ASP.NET, you could just use the same regular expression [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) uses. Presumably most email addresses are not going to be invalid, so the `Try...Catch` operation shouldn't be too expensive.

```
MailAddress mailAddress;

try 
{
    mailAddress = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    //Email considered invalid
}
```

Edit 2 - This one should work with the validator:

```
(\s?)+\w+(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+([;.](([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}){1,25})+)*(\s?)+
```

Just be aware, email validation cannot be considered reliable because it's very easy to bypass most of the regular expressions.

Comment: Hi I need client side validation not server side.

Comment: If it's for performance reasons, `RegularExpressionValidator` uses both, client (when available) and server side, validation anyway. I'd perform a Javascript validation (e.g. http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/javascript-validation/) and pass in your trimmed textbox as the value. If it succeeds, perform the server side validation above otherwise display an error message.

Comment: I know, we validate by lot of ways. But I want a regular expression that allow white space in both end

Comment: Hi  keyboardP
Please read my question again. Your expression does not allow whitespace neither end or start

Comment: I've tested it on this site and it seems to allow whitespaces on both ends whereas your original one doesn't: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ I'll see if I can test it in an ASP.NET project.

Comment: Seems like the validator is working differently for whatever reason. I've cross checked the regex with a few other sites such as a http://regexhero.net/tester/ and it works there but it doesn't work the validator.

Comment: I thought I'd try again with the ASP.NET validator and modified your original one. Should work with spaces on both ends and with the validator.